# I'm trying to reduce the cell value in the column by 1 with duplicate and if condition

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, duplicates, formula

I'm working on an inventory replenishment tool. If column E says PICK and the barcode in Column A is Duplicate then the cell value (Warehouse stock) should reduce by 1 from Column C, else the same WH stock value in Column C.
Please find the attached Screen shot:

[image]

Formula i tried,
IF(E3="PICK",IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$9,$A3)>1,C3-ROW(A1),C3))

Comment: You mean that the value in column D should continue to reduce by one each time the code from column A appears with a "Pick" in column E?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it should present the previous stock value.

Comment: hi tylen i'm having one more question in if condition for creating target revision tool. could you please take a look at it.

Comment: A link would be nice.

Comment: hello, Teylyn. Hope you are doing well. I'm trying to look up the column value based on the cells inside the table and its row. However, my values inside my table could be anywhere between the given number so it must always return the next greatest matching value.  Below i'm giving out the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648041/multiple-if-condition-excel-matrix-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nested IF formula that must be confirmed with Ctrl+ Shift + Enter. Also, you do not want to use whole column references, but use references with defined row numbers otherwise your workbook will get very slow.

```
=IF(E3="PICK",IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A3,$A3)>1,MIN(IF($A$2:A2=A3,$D$2:$D2))-1,IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A3,$A3)=1,C3-1)),MIN(IF($A$2:A2=A3,$D$2:$D2)))
```

Note the placement of the $ signs in the references. The first row of a range reference will have a $ sign in front of the row number like $D$2, so the range always starts in row 2. But the end of the range is variable, depending on the current row and it does not have a $ sign in front of the row number. That way you can calculate based on the values in the rows above the current row.

Let's break this down.

When the cell in column E is "Pick" , the formula counts how many rows above and including the current row have the same code as the current row. If that is greater than one, we have a duplicate code, so the formula will use the minimum value of the rows above in column D that have the same area code, and subtract one.

But if this is the first time the area code appears, the formula takes the stock value from column C in the same row and subtracts 1.

That deals with all the possibilities for the "Pick" values in column E.

If column E is not "pick", then we only want the minimum value of the rows above in column D, where the area code is the same as in column A.

If you have Office 365, you can use the MinIFS function instead of the Min(IF()) construct, and you don't have to use Ctrl + Shift + Enter (not even if you use the first formula).

```
=IF(E7="PICK",IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A7,$A7)>1,MINIFS($D$2:D6,$A$2:$A6,A7)-1,IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A7,$A7)=1,C7-1)),MINIFS($D$2:D6,$A$2:$A6,A7))
```

[image]

Strictly speaking, you don't need the innermost nested IF that checks if the area code appears for the first time, but it helps understand the business logic when the formula is no longer fresh in your mind. You can shorten it to this (Office 365 version)

```
=IF(E3="PICK",
IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A3,$A3)>1,
    MINIFS($D$2:D2,$A$2:$A2,A3)-1,
    C3-1),
MINIFS($D$2:D2,$A$2:$A2,A3))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the help.