# Multiple if condition excel, Matrix structure

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, nested

|  | Box type | Box type | Box type | Box type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BinLoc | 810 | 811 | 911 | 822 |
| S1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| S2 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| S3 | 12 | 6 | 6 | 3 |
| S4 | 24 | 12 | 12 | 6 |
| R1 | 48 | 24 | 24 | 12 |
| R2 | 96 | 48 | 48 | 24 |

Well 810,811,911,822 are box type and s1,s2,s3,s4,r1,r2 are bin location, I need to find out which bin location should I choose based on the input (Ex: Box type = 810 and No of boxes = 5) since 5 lies within 4 to 12 in `810 box type` the bin location is `S3`

Ex data

So I tried multiple if condition I couldn't do it. Please help

| SUP | INVOICE NUMBER | Qty | Box Type | Bin Loc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 2 | 810 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 2 | 811 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 2 | 822 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 3 | 810 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 3 | 811 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 4 | 810 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 4 | 811 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 4 | 822 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 5 | 810 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 5 | 811 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 5 | 911 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 6 | 810 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 6 | 811 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 6 | 822 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 7 | 810 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 7 | 911 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 8 | 810 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 8 | 811 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 9 | 811 |  |
| 92 | ACAMP206186 | 10 | 810 |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand question correctly then you can try below formula.

```
=XLOOKUP(I2,INDEX($B$3:$E$8,,MATCH(J2,$B$2:$E$2,0)),$A$3:$A$8,,-1)
```

`XLOOKUP()` is only available to `EXCEL-365`. For older version may try below formula but `Box Type` data must be sorted.

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$8,MATCH(I2,INDEX($B$3:$E$8,,MATCH(J2,$B$2:$E$2,0)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: hi @Harun24HR, I need help here. Actually, the value should return the greater number, not the lesser number. Ex: 911 and 7 should return S4 (Whatever the value comes between 7 to 12 should return S4, not S3). I tried altering your formula but getting errors.

Comment: Which formula you are using `XLOOKUP()` or `MATCH()`?

Comment: Match() formula

Comment: Then try `=INDEX($A$3:$A$8,MATCH(I2,INDEX($B$3:$E$8,,MATCH(J2,$B$2:$E$2,0)),-1))`

Comment: Yeah I tried this one =INDEX($A$3:$A$8,MATCH(I2,INDEX($B$3:$E$8,,MATCH(J2,$B$2:$E$2,0)),-1))  but getting #N/A

Comment: It should work. Then there may some other issue. Can you try with few sample data then apply to yor real sheet.